# Proxy from iPhone to desktop running Fiddler some https fails

Tags: ios, iphone, proxy, fiddler

I am successfully seeing https traffic from a proxy setup on an iPhone to a wifi network so that it is routed through a desktop running fiddler. However, some http requests fail. I have all items checked under options > https. Ideas?

Comment: The documentation on this link helped me out... http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForiOS

Answer (score 0):

See http://groups.google.com/group/httpfiddler/browse_thread/thread/55b865509faaf119

Short answer is that a different certificate generation strategy is needed to interoperate with iOS based products. This will be coming in the next few weeks.

Comment: Step 2 does not prompt with root cert. It just repeates over and over in fiddler showing me the request to 192.168.1.100:8888 with no result status. I just use safari to do this on the iPhone, right?

Comment: You need to use the machine name, not the IP.